# When Ethereum burns, who's Ethereum is burning?

Tags: go-ethereum

Before the Merge update, people mined Ethereum. So eventually, Ethereum needs to be located in exchanges to sell or private wallets to hold. When Ethereum burns, then who's Ethereum burning?

Answer (score 1):

The Ethereum that burns is transaction fees.

It belongs (belonged) to the users who pay the transaction fee to have their transaction included in the Ethereum blockchain blocks.